# Trouble writing simple command line calculator

Tags: java

I have some conditions:

1. only integers (negative and positive numbers)
2. addition (+)
3. subtraction (-)
4. (=) equals sign to stop and display the result.

I did it, but there are some problems..
Problem is, when I entered firstly to command-line: `127 + 3`, it is okey, but then, when I entered `-`, it stops and says that:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
  at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:840)
  at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1461)
  at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2387)
  at Calculator2.main(Calculator2.java:14)
```

My code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*; //just for insurance

public class Calculator2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Welcome to the Best Calculator");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        double first, second, ans = 0;
        char operand;
        while (true) {
            first = sc.nextDouble();
            operand = sc.next().charAt(0);
            second = sc.nextDouble();
            if (operand != '=') {
                switch (operand) {
                case '+':
                    ans += (first + second);
                    break;
                case '-':
                    ans -= (first - second);
                    break;
                }
            } else if (operand == '=') {
                System.out.println("The result is: " + ans);
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Some examples:

> Welcome to the Best Calculator 
>        127 + 3 
>        - 
>        40 
>        = 
>        The result is: 90

Need help, I hope there are a lot of good people)

Comment: You should really rephrase your title

Comment: *"I did it, but there are some problems.."* ***What*** problems?

Comment: Edited title. Still not ideal, but best I could do with that lack of information on what's the actual problem.

Comment: Your `else if` is redundant. A simple `else` would be enough.

Comment: The exception is because you ask for another `first` value, when what you really want is to implicitly use the previous answer as `first`. Try moving the declaration of `first` outside the loop. When you get your answer, store that value back into `first`.